# Working with cursors using Net::Twitter in Perl

Tags: perl, twitter

I am mining Twitter using Net::Twitter interface to Twitter's REST API. I am able to obtain a timeline with search terms, specifying parameters like language and size of the return.

```
use Net::Twitter;
use Data::Dumper;
use Encode;
$, = "\t", $\ = "\n";

$consumer_key = q(<yourKey>);
$consumer_secret = q(<yourSecret>);
$access_token = q(<yourToken>);
$access_token_secret = q(<yourTokenSecret>);

my $t = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits              => [qw/API::RESTv1_1/],
    consumer_key        => $consumer_key,
    consumer_secret     => $consumer_secret,
    access_token        => $access_token,
    access_token_secret => $access_token_secret,
);

my $search_term = q(@Monsanto);
my $result = $t->search($search_term, {lang => 'en', count => 100});

my $identity; # Last returned id 
foreach my $status (@{$result->{'statuses'}}) {
    $identity = $status->{id};              # Tweet ID
    print $status->{user}->{screen_name};   # Screen Name
    my $s = $status->{text};                # Tweeted Text
    $s =~ s/[^[:ascii:]]+//g;               # Strip Non-ASCII Encoded Characters
    print $identity . '|' . $s;             # Tweet ID | Tweeted Text
};
print 'STOPPED at ' . $identity;            # ID of the last tweet
```

Twitter limits the quantum of search results returned in any one search query. Extending the timeline beyond rate-limits requires cursoring. Typically, one obtains the id of the last (oldest) tweet and sets that to the max. id of the next query. HERE IS WHERE NET::TWITTER APPEARS TO BREAK DOWN.

```
my $result2 = $t->search($search_term, {max_id => $identity});
foreach my $status (@{$result2->{'statuses'}}) {
    $identity = $status->{id};   
    print $status->{user}->{screen_name};
    my $s = $status->{text}; 
    $s =~ s/[^[:ascii:]]+//g; 
    print $identity . '|' . $s;
};
print 'STOPPED at ' . $identity;
```

I am running Perl on a 32-bit Win XP OS. I have tried a number of approaches. First, I tried substituting the numeric id as a string in place of the variable.

```
my $result2 = $t->search($search_term, {max_id => 406729969746722816});
```

Or

```
my $result2 = $t->search($search_term, {max_id => '406729969746722816'});
```

No change. I have tested the query on Twitter's dev. console and verified that the REST API works.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you never found an answer, maybe you need to use a 64-bit system, because it looks like you're using 'id' rather than 'id_str'. The numeric tweet IDs may now be bigger than your 32-bit system can handle.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines